# Javascript retrieving username from db

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a JavaScript function that retrieves surname that corresponds to a supplied email address with no success so far. Here's my code:

```
function getUsername(){

var username;

$(function(){
    var dataString = 'email=' + EMAIL_ADDRESS;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'user_crud_operations.php',
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            U = data[1];
            username = data;          
        }
    });  
 });

return username;

}
```

I need to use the retrieved username in another function elsewhere. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, you'll need to call a callback with your data, or use a Promise.

Comment: Where are you going right is more the question. Ajax will not return the data where you expect it now. You need to turn your code inside out

Comment: @all this question is asked a dozen times a day; bookmark "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call" and close these as duplicates with as little fanfare as possible

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous functions (as used in AJAX) usually do not return values but instead trigger callback functions.

You must restructure your design so that "getUserName()" passes to a callback instead of returning a value.  For example:

```javascript
function getUsername(handler) {
  // ...
  $.ajax({
    // ...
  }).done(function(username) {
    if (handler && (typeof(handler)==='function')) {
      handler(username);
    }
  });
}

// Sample usage...
getUsername(function(username) {
  alert("OK: username=" + username);
});
```